# confused about apache server virtual host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, directory, virtual

So I configured a VirtualHost in the httpd-vhosts.conf directory, but whenever I navigate to the servername, it seems to always give me the page listed in httpd.conf.

I am new to apache web server and am not sure what else I need to do.

In my httpd-vhosts.conf I have

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

#                                                                                                                                          
# VirtualHost example:                                                                                                                     
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.                                                                         
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not                                                                       
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.                                                                            
#                                                                                                                                          
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName helloworld.com
   DocumentRoot /Users/username/Desktop/RailsDemo/depot/public/
  <Directory /Users/username/Desktop/RailsDemo/depot/public/>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In my httpd.conf, I have default settings, so I didn't change anything since install.

Also, I have matched helloworld.com to the correct ip address. Typing helloworld.com into the browser produces the wrong view...it produces the view indicated in httpd.conf.

If this helps, I am trying to do p. 238 of Pragmatic Agile Web Development with Ruby on Rails (4th Edition) -- Iteration K1: Deploying with Phusion Passenger and MySQL

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be running Mac OS X. In your httpd.conf, you will have the lines;

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Remove the comment, making it

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Restart apache, and that should activate your named vhost.

Comment: Hmm. Now I have "You don't have permission to access / on this server"

Comment: @stack-dot-push Then the web server process does not have permission to access your home directory. You'll need to put the server root somewhere else where it has permission.

Comment: that is not working either... I included vhosts. I am also using apache web server locally, so on my own computer. So isn't the server root supposed to have permission already? My server root is set to "/usr"

Comment: @stack-dot-push Sorry, I meant DocumentRoot, it points to `/Users/username/Desktop/RailsDemo/depot/public/` which is probably read protected from other users, including the user the web server runs as.